# How to stop a nohup process running rails server on port 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

I have started a rails server puma by using the following command.

```
 nohup rails server &
```

its output was [2] 22481 along with the following:

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

But now I have forget the returned process id, so how can I detect the process id so as to delete the process on aws.

Answer (score 2):

To kill whatever is on port 3000 (webrick server default port), type this below command to get process id for 3000 port:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

Then, use process id (PID) to kill the process:

```
$ kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 1):

command

```
ps -ef
```

return the full output list of processes in which one of the list item is as:

```
ec2-user 12992     1  0 Dec20 ?        00:00:57 puma 3.12.0 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [tukatech_garmentstore_live]
```

so force killed the process by.

```
kill -9 12992
```

did the job

Answer (score 1):

Rails server process pid can be found in this directory: 
->  tmp/pids/server.pid

then,

Kill -9 pid

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux|grep 3000
```

This will give you rails server id running on port 3000